# When I am Scrolling my RecyclerView, the item inside is automatically changing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to kotlin and using it one of my new project which is related to booking appointments I am comparing data of one list which are the booked slots with the text of item of recycler view when am doing some scrolling the data is automatically updating

## BeforeScrolling

[image]

## AfterScrolling

[image]

## When  adding Else Block

[image]

## Recycler View Adapter Class

```
class TimesSlotAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val timeSlotsList: List<TimeSlots>,
    val filledSlotList: List<BookedSlotsData>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TimesSlotAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var mItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(
                context
            ).inflate(R.layout.item_timeslots, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = timeSlotsList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(timeSlotsList[position])

        for (timeSlots in filledSlotList) {
            if (holder.textView.text.toString().equals(timeSlots.time.toString())) {
                Log.i("time1",timeSlots.time.toString())
                Log.i("time2",holder.textView.text.toString())
                holder.card.setBackground(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.card_background))
                holder.itemView.isEnabled=false
            }
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            mItemClickListener!!.onItemClick(
                holder.itemView,
                position,
                timeSlotsList[position]
            )
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int, model: TimeSlots)
    }

    fun SetOnItemClickListener(mItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        var textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeSlots)
        var card: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card)
        fun bind(timeSlots: TimeSlots) {
            textView.text = timeSlots.name
        }

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        //4
        override fun onClick(v: View) {

        }
    }

}
```

## Booked Slots DataModel

```
class BookedSlotsData {

    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    var time: String? = null

}
```

## Time Slots DataModel

```
data class TimeSlots(val name: String?)
```

## Adapter Initialisation

```
val adapter =
                TimesSlotAdapter(activity, viewModel.oldFilteredMorningTime, bookedTime)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter

            adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(object : TimesSlotAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int, model: TimeSlots) {
                    var intent = Intent(context, AppointmentDetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("Time Slots", model.name)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

            })
```

Comment: You need to add else part in `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happening because this is how `RecyclerView` works it recycle your view when ever you scroll and only use current loaded screen data in to memory.

As soon as you scroll bottom and come up your position mis match and you see some weird and unexpected result in Item.

You can solve this issue simply by providing `else` block to your design changing condition Like in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
         if (holder.textView.text.toString().equals(timeSlots.time.toString())) {
                Log.i("time1",timeSlots.time.toString())
                Log.i("time2",holder.textView.text.toString())

 holder.card.setBackground(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.card_background))
                holder.itemView.isEnabled=false
            }
           else{
 holder.card.setBackground(context.resources.getDrawable(//your another drawable))
                holder.itemView.isEnabled=true
            }
```

That's how you can solve it.

Comment: on Adding the Else block getting another error kindly check above

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzERO.jpg now the item should have been disabled was also enabled

Comment: something is wrong in your implementation let me check it once again and also why you used loop in your onbindView

Comment: {"BookedTime":[{"time":"08:00 AM"},{"time":"11:00 AM"}]}     I am getting this as server response     My Other list  is having time at the interval of 10 min from 8:00 AM to 12:00 AM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198858/discussion-between-daksh-semwal-and-arbaz-pirwani).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, after researching whole sof, holder.setIsRecyclable(false); works for me..

here is example of my oncreateviewholder in that adapter..
good luck :)

```
  View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_time_slot, viewGroup, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    return holder;
}
```